# Retrieve HTMLTable from client side in server side (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, client-side, server-side, html-table

I have an `HTML table` on a simple Webform.
This table is constructed dynamically (based on a SQL Express DB) in the Page_Load.
Then my page is shown and my user can modify the content of the table cells (which are div) via drag&drop.
After that, I have to call a code behind method to update the new position of my elements in my table.
The problem is that I am using an `asp:imagebutton` which do a postback.
So, I am losing all the changes made in the client side before step in my OnClick method.

The only way that I have found is to retrieve the inner HTML of my parent div element (which is the parentNode of my table), inject it in a hidden input (on the OnClientCLick event by Javascript) and retrieve it in my server side. But, in this way, I am losing all my control hierarchy:

```
    parent.InnerHtml = Request.Form["innerHTML"];
```

The final purpose is to loop on my HTMLTable.
Rows element after hitting my imagebutton and update my DB with my client modified table.

Thx a lot for your help

Comment: Finally, I used 2 hiddenfield, One with a JSON string with my modified value and one is the HTML code of my table.